# Morphing software in Linux

Tags: animation

I'm trying to morph from one video to another (not just two photographs). At the moment I'm using `gtkmorh`, but AFAIK it only allows photograph morphing and not sequence morphing.

Does anyone know what options are available (if any) to morph video sequences in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have lot of experience in working with video in Linux, however, there is [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), which is capable with [video editing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te9HFQVaSUE), and it also can morph [still images](https://vimeo.com/83384457) and [meshes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5V0YC29AKU). And of course [more complex 3D objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeHm_IHeheg).

Maybe you can achieve your goal, by combining those techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am aware of Blender and the posibility of morphing still images modifying the vertex of a plane, the problem is morphing from one video sequence to another. If you know a method for doing that I would really appreciate you pointing to that method.